# Properly join users table when there is both createdBy and updatedBy

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a table `environments` that has both a `createdBy` field, as well as an `updatedBy` field. These fields store a member ID.

There is also a table `members` which houses the ID and the username. Below are the queries to create the tables

```
CREATE TABLE `environments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdBy` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdDtTm` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedBy` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedDtTm` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `member_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `login` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `passwd` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

I would like to write a query that displays all the environments, but instead of an ID showing, I'd the the user name to show. Since they can be different though, I'm not sure how to write the join statement. Ideas?

Comment: If you are joining the same table twice, you will want to use aliases. Also is there a reason why createdBy and updatedBy are not ints?

Comment: yeah. me being careless. I went from v1 (where those were hardcoded values of usernames) to v2 (where there was a members table) and forgot to update the table schema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a double join. SOmething along the lines of

```
SELECT
  environments.*,
  creators.firstname AS cfirstname,
  creators.lastname AS clastname,
  updaters.firstname AS ufirstname,
  updaters.lasstname AS ulastname
FROM
  environments
  INNER JOIN members AS creators ON environments.createdBy=creators.login
  LEFT JOIN members AS updaters ON environments.updatedBy=updaters.login
WHERE -- whatever
```

Comment: ah ok. that makes sense. Thanks! 6 minutes on the timer for the checkmark